# Ethereum Wallet (Mist) on Win7: connect via http proxy to JSON RPC Endpoint in Internet

Tags: mist, json-rpc, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have the Ethereum Wallet (Mist) running on a Win7 client. The access to internet is only allowed via the corporate's http proxy server. Is it possible to configure Mist to use the http proxy for Internet connections?

I tried setting the environment variable `http_proxy`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring a proxy isn't possible yet.

See

- https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/165
- https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1385